# Bucle infinito Nodemon Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, bucles

Mi aplicacion es un chatbot en nodejs, que funciona a travez del paquete npm whatsapp-web.js que trabaja con eventos y asi queda a la espera de los mensajes que reciba para procesarlos y responder

Le instale el paquete Nodemon, para ejecutar automaticamente si suceden cambios, pero nunca llega a ejecutarse el chatbot, se queda en un bucle

Cuando el chatbot se inicio correctamente sale *chatbot conectado...*

[![este es el blucle que genera nodemon][1]][1]

[image: Aqui cuando se ejecuta sin nodemon]

[image: Verificar si hay archivos para iniciar el chatbot]

porque me sale este bucle, nodemon no trabaja con eventos? como puedo solucionarlo?

muchas gracias

Comment: Cuál es el contenido de `app.js`? Es modificado por algún evento de los que mencionas?

Comment: Este es https://pastebin.com/P47R8j8N, no modifico los eventos, es propio del paquete npm whatsapp-web.js

Comment: Podrías agregar el flag `--verbose` y compartir el resultado?, tal vez nos proporcione más pistas de porqué se reinicia.

Comment: entiendo que son banderas, para permitir una acción, pero no se como implementar específicamente --verbose

Comment: ¿Cuesta mucho hacer un [mcve]? Por otro lado, supongo que usas `nodemon` sólo como parte del proceso de desarrollo. Por último, hay algo que tu bot hace, con algún fichero (archivo) y `nodemon` lo está tomando como un cambio. Para eso es necesario ver el código, y no es bien visto ponerlo en un pastebin. Saudos

Comment: Simplementa agregas la bandera al comando `nodemon --verbose app.js`. Y como lo menciona @MauricioContreras, esto es para ver si los archivos `.json` con los que trabajas dentro de `app.js` son los que están causando ese "bucle" de reinicios, puesto que nodemon no solo escucha por cambios a archivos `.js`.

Comment: El chatbot, para conectar con un numero celular, este previamente escanea un codigo qr y este dato se guarda como json, el chatbot lee este archivo y se conecta al celular, ademas durante el proceso el chatbot guarda la conversacion en archivos .json mientras va escuchando peticiones, ya actualize la imagen

Comment: Pues ahí lo tienes, el archivo `session.json` es el causante de esos reinicios puesto que trabajas con él dentro de tu aplicación y nodemon hace un reinicio cada vez que detecta un cambio sobre ese archivo -el `.json`-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu aplicación se está reiniciando a causa del archivo `session.json`. Esto debido a que según la [documentación de nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#specifying-extension-watch-list):

> By default, nodemon looks for files with the .js, .mjs, .coffee, .litcoffee, and .json extensions.

Cualquier cambio a algún archivo (en el directorio del proyecto) con esa extensión ocasionará un reinicio. Por lo que tienes varias opciones:

- Pensar en otro método para procesar y almacenar tu sesión.
- Ignorar completamente los archivos `.json` con la bandera `--ignore`:

  - Con un patrón: `nodemon --ignore *.json` .
  - Colocando el archivo `session.json` dentro de un directorio `sessions/` por ejemplo e ignorando el mismo: `nodemon --ignore sessions/`.
- Asumiendo que no solo lo ocuparás para el proceso de desarrollo -es decir, para producción-, no utilizar nodemon.
- Utilizar [`node-dev`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dev).